# Copy files to different location created one hour Ago

Tags: windows, ms-dos

I want to create one batch file to copy files from one location to another which are created one hour Ago. I tried to use xcopy /d but it does not accept time.

Can you please suggest.

thanks.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? You want to copy all files older than one hour from a specific folder to another isn't it?

Comment: Basically I want to remove those files which are older than hour.

Comment: Hi christophe, thanks for your comment. I am using Windows 7

Comment: Hi CharleiRB , yes it is the same, but I am not getting how to use /XO command here

Comment: If you have a question about how to use the XO option specifically, then create a new question, and ask a specific question about using the /XO option of Robocopy.  Explain what you don't get and include your research (what you've tried, what the results were, etc.). Perhaps also reference the question and answers pointed out to you here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 offers a new shell more powerful than classic DOS, it is called PowerShell.
PowerShell can be opened with the "Start Menu > All Programs > Administrative Tools > Windows PowerShell" shortcut.

You will need to run this command once to enable scripts to run on your computer:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then you just have to create the script (.ps1 file extension) and the following code lines will delete files older than one hour in a specific folder:

```
$myFolder = 'C:\Temp'
$filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Path $myFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $(Get-Date).AddHours(-1)}
$filesToDelete | Remove-Item -Force
```

Replace 'C:\Temp' with your folder path.

Be cautious with that script, it will delete files without prompting.